# How can I generate a random float number?

Tags: c

I'm trying to generate a random float number between 0 and 1.

```
0.0f + rand() % 1.0f;
```

But I get the following error after I compile with GCC:

```
error: invalid operands to binary % (have ‘int’ and ‘float’)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure modular arithmetic only works on integers because any other kind of number can just use regular division and mod loses its purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, this solved my question.(float)rand() / (float)(RAND_MAX / 1.0f)